# Convexity and Lipschitz continuity

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, inequalities, convex-analysis

It is probably an easy question, but somehow I am stuck.

**Question** Is the following statement true? If yes, how to prove it?

> Suppose that $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is convex and
> $$
> \langle\nabla f(x)-\nabla f(y),x-y\rangle \leq L|x-y|^2
> $$
> for some $L>0$ and all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Does it follow that
> $$
> |\nabla f(x)-\nabla f(y)|\leq L|x-y|
> $$
> for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's a standard result in convex optimization. For example Theorem 2.1.5 in Nesterov's "Introductory Lectures on Convex Optimization" states that the following are equivalent:

- $f$ is $C^1$, convex and the gradient $\nabla f$ is $L$-Lipschitz
- for all $x,y$: $0\leq f(y) - f(x) - \langle\nabla f(x),y-x\rangle \leq \tfrac{L}2
  \|x-y\|^2$
- for all $x,y$: $\tfrac1L\|\nabla f(x)-\nabla f(y)\|^2 \leq \langle\nabla f(x)-\nabla f(y),x-y\rangle$
- for all $x,y$: $\langle\nabla f(x)-\nabla f(y),x-y\rangle \leq L\|x-y\|^2$

(In case you are interested: The proof there is directly for $C^1$ functions and no second derivatives are used at intermediate steps.)

Answer (score 9):

**Yes**

Consider first the case where $f\in{\cal C}^2$. Then
$$\nabla f(y)-\nabla f(x)=\int_0^1{\rm D}^2f(x+t(y-x))\cdot(y-x)\,dt.$$
There follows
$$\|\nabla f(y)-\nabla f(x)\|\le\|y-x\|\int_0^1\|{\rm D}^2f(x+t(y-x))\|\,dt.$$
Now, the assumption tels you that $\|{\rm D}^2f(x+t(y-x))\|\le L$, whence the result.

Now the general case can be obtained by a density argument. Let a convex function $f$ satisfy your assumption. For $\epsilon>0$, et us define a smooth convex function $f_\epsilon$ by inf-convolution:
$$f_\epsilon(x)=\inf_z(f(z)+\frac1\epsilon\,\|x-z\|^2).$$
Apply the result to $f_\epsilon$, then pass to the limit as $\epsilon\rightarrow0$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Since it is too long, I will split it into two comments: (1) My understanding is that you used the following argument: by passing to the limit with difference quotient, the condition that I have implies $\langle D^2f(x)u,u\rangle\leq L$ for any $|u|=1$ and hence $|\langle D^2f(x)u,u\rangle|\leq L$, because convexity implies $D^2f(x)\geq 0$. Then the spectral theorem for symmetric matrices yields $\Vert D^2f(x)\Vert=\sup_{|u|=1}|\langle D^2f(x)u,u\rangle|\leq L$. Here, $\Vert D^2f(x)\Vert$ is the operator norm.

Comment: (2) I think the inf-convolution is only $C^{1,1}$ and this is not an obvious fact. While your argument works for $C^{1,1}$ functions, it is delicate in that case as $D^2f$ exists a.e. only. I think it is much easier to use approximation by standard mollification. Please, let me know if both of my comments make sense.

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz. Yes, your comments do make sense. 1st one : you correctly point out that the symmetry of the Hessian is an important ingredient.

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz. Your 2nd comment. Well, I am not familiar with inf-convolution. But there are other ways to regularize a convex function. One of them is to consider its Legendre transform, then to add $\epsilon\rho$ where $\rho$ is smooth convex with $\nabla\rho$ bounded, then to transform back.

Answer (score 4):

This answer is a small modification of the answer of Denis Serre. I added for reader's convenience: (1) the result is slightly more general; (2) the answer contains much more details; (3) I am using a convolution by mollification approximation instead of inf-convolution.

Since convex functions satisfy
$$
\langle \nabla f(x)-\nabla f(y),x-y\rangle\geq 0,
$$
it suffices to prove the following more general result.

> **Theorem.**
> Let $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and let $L>0$.Then the following conditions are equivalent:
> \begin{equation}
> (1)\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ |\langle\nabla f(x)-\nabla f(y),x-y\rangle|\leq L|x-y|^2    
> \quad
> \text{for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$.}
> \end{equation}
> \begin{equation}
> (2)\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ |\nabla f(x)-\nabla f(y)|\leq L|x-y|    
> \quad
> \text{for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$.}
> \end{equation}

**Proof.**
While the implication (2) to (1) is obvious the other is not so we will prove the implication from (2) to (1) now.
Assume first that $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$. For $|u|=1$, (1) yields,
$$
\left|\left\langle\frac{\nabla f(x+tu)-\nabla f(x)}{t},u\right\rangle\right|\leq L,
$$
so passing to the limit as $t\to 0$ gives
$$
|\langle D^2f(x)u,u\rangle|\leq L.
$$
Since $D^2 f(x)$ is a symmetric matrix, the spectral theorem implies that the operator norm of the matrix $D^2f(x)$ satisfies
$$
\Vert D^2f(x)\Vert = \sup_{|u|=1}|\langle D^2f(x)u,u\rangle|\leq L.
$$
This estimate however, easily implies the result
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
& |\nabla f(x)-\nabla f(y)|=
\left|\int_0^1\frac{d}{dt}\nabla f(y+t(x-y))\, dt\right|\\
&\leq |x-y|\int_0^1\Vert D^2f(y+t(x-y))\Vert\, dt\leq L|x-y|.
\end{split}    
\end{equation}
This completes the proof when$f\in C^\infty$. Assume now that $f\in C^1$ and let $f_\epsilon=f*\varphi_\epsilon$ be a standard approximation by convolution. Recall that $f_\epsilon\in C^\infty$ and $\nabla f_\epsilon=(\nabla f)*\varphi_\epsilon$. We have
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
& 
|\langle \nabla f_\epsilon(x)-\nabla f_\epsilon(y),x-y\rangle|=
\Big|\Big\langle\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} (\nabla f(x-z)-\nabla f(y-z))\varphi_\epsilon(z)\, dz,x-y\Big\rangle\Big|\\
&\leq
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} 
\big|\big\langle \nabla f(x-z)-\nabla f(y-z)),(x-z)-(y-z)\big\rangle\big|\, \varphi_\epsilon(z)\, dz
\leq L|x-y|^2,
\end{split}    
\end{equation}
where the last inequality is a consequence of (1) and $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\varphi_\epsilon=1$.
Since $f_\epsilon\in C^\infty$, the first part of the proof yields
$$
|\nabla f_\epsilon(x)-\nabla f_\epsilon(y)|\leq L|x-y|
$$
and the result follows upon passing to the limit as $\epsilon\to 0$.

Answer (score 3):

A partial answer: if you're willing to strengthen your assumption and suppose $f\in C^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then yes. Otherwise, I'm not sure.

---

Functions that satisfy -
$$\langle\nabla f(x)-\nabla f(y),x-y\rangle \leq L\|x-y\|^2$$
are called "L-semi-concave", and functions that satisfy -
$$\|\nabla f(x)-\nabla f(y)\|\leq L\|x-y\|$$
are called "L-smooth".

If $f\in C^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is both at least L-semi-convex (in particular, convex) and at-least L-semi-convave - then it is indeed L-smooth.

One may prove it by considering the Hessian $\nabla^2f$ of $f$: the convexity implies it is positive semidefinite, and the semi-concavity implies that $\nabla^2f-\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{Id}$ is negative semidefinite. Therefore, the operator-norm of $\nabla^2f$ must be bounded, which means that $\nabla f$ is Lipschitz (i.e. $f$ is L-smooth).

I'm not sure if it still holds under the weaker assumption $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Comment: If you approximate a $C^1$, convex, "L-semiconcave" function $f$ by convolution with a smooth nonnegative kernel, you get a sequence of smooth convex L-semiconcave functions converging $C^1$ to $f$, so the smooth case is sufficient.

Comment: Thank you, but could you add references? Without any references the answer is not useful since the facts that you mentioned are not obvious.