# Reference request for equivalent Lipschitz smoothness conditions

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, inequalities, continuity

For an open set $Z\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$, let $f: Z\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ be a continuously differentiable function on $Z$, and let $L>0$ be fixed. Also, suppose that (a) $f$ is nonconvex and (b) $f$ is not twice differentiable.

Does anyone have references in any books or journal papers that prove that the following conditions are equivalent?

1. $\|\nabla f(x)- \nabla f(y)\| \leq L \|x-y\|$ for every $x, y\in Z$.
2. $|f(x) - f(y) - \langle \nabla f(y), x-y\rangle| \leq \dfrac{L}{2}\|x-y\|$ for every $x, y\in Z$.

I know that there are smoothing arguments (some of which are sketched in [these](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4227159/characterization-of-lipschitz-derivative) [posts](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/374761/convexity-and-lipschitz-continuity)) and more fundamental arguments (see, for example, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4227159/characterization-of-lipschitz-derivative)) that can be made.
However, I have yet to find these arguments in any textbooks or papers.